# Nginx redirect port to url

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect, port

I'm running a VPS that has VestaCP installed. The web panel runs on port `8083`. I've managed to get it working on `panel.domain.com` however, some of the URL's in the panel lose functionality when using the subdomain.

I was wondering how I get port `8083` to point to `domain.com/panel`.

Here's what i have tried in my nginx config:

```
server {
  listen        108.xx.xx.xxx:443;
  server_name domain.com;

  root /var/www/ghost;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location /panel {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8083;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your VestaCP control panel via `domain.com/panel`, you can use this nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 108.xx.xx.xxx:443;
    server_name domain.com;

    root /var/www/ghost;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location ~ /panel(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^ https://domain.com:8083$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

This makes nginx send a 301 redirect for all URIs beginning with `/panel` to `https://domain.com:8083`, therefore allowing you to access the panel via `https://domain.com/panel`.

However, all the URLs that are generated in the VestaCP panel still point directly to `https://domain.com:8083`. If you want to change those to begin with `https://domain.com/panel`, you need to modify VestaCP. VestaCP might not have an option to change the domain directly, so you might need to modify VestaCP code directly, which I don't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

What's running on port 8083 is your web panel, which I presume is not based on Nginx. To make port 8083 "point to" anything, you need to customize how your web panel is behaving, not Nginx.

Perhaps you want the reverse of what you are asking, to have Nginx listen on port 80 or 433 and redirect or proxy `domain.com/panel` to the web panel?

You should also clarify  your "point to" language to be either "redirect to" or "proxy to".